# How to change from POSIXct to just time in R

Tags: r, time

I am new to R. I am trying to change column to just a time without PM or AM. Just H:MM:SS.

```r
Friday_length
<S3: POSIXct>
Satuarday_length
<S3: POSIXct>
ride_length_average
<S3: POSIXct>
1899-12-31 00:23:50 1899-12-31 00:28:33 1899-12-31 00:26:48
1899-12-31 00:13:12 1899-12-31 00:15:35 1899-12-31 00:13:40
1899-12-31 02:40:41 1899-12-31 02:51:04 1899-12-31 02:38:04
```

Above is a example. `ride_length_average` is listed as `1899-12-31 00:26:48`. I just wanted `00:26:48`. Maybe I am missing something. I tried `mutate(ride_length_average, ride_length_average2 = POSIXct("ride_length_average", format="%H:%M:%S"))`.

Thanks

I trying to change columns from POSITct to time formatted like H:M:S.  Thanks

Comment: The difftime class might be worth investigating.

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix would be converting it to [hms](https://hms.tidyverse.org/index.html):

```r
hms::as_hms(as.POSIXct("1899-12-31 00:23:50"))
#> 00:23:50
```

Though you must be doing something a bit weird if you ended up having `POSIXct` as time difference value. Subtracting one *POSIXct* from another (or using `difftime()` should return a proper difftime object which would be more suitable for calculations:

```r
datetime_1 <- as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 12:00")
datetime_2 <- as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 12:15")
(diff_1 <- difftime(datetime_2,datetime_1))
#> Time difference of 15 mins
(diff_2 <- datetime_2 - datetime_1)
#> Time difference of 15 mins
diff_1 == diff_2
#> [1] TRUE
as.numeric(diff_1, units = "secs")
#> [1] 900
as.numeric(diff_1, units = "hours")
#> [1] 0.25

# hms is based on difftime class but might be a bit more convenient to use
hms::as_hms(diff_1)
#> 00:15:00
hms::as_hms(diff_1) * 10
#> Time difference of 9000 secs
hms::as_hms(diff_1  * 10)
#> 02:30:00
```